# Labels with strings and values in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, numbers, label

I am trying to add labels to each column of my file (File1) in Matlab. I would like to add as some of the labels strings with values.
I tried:

```
myFile1 = vertcat({'subject','5_59ms','6_69ms','7_79ms','number','condition'}, myFile1);
```

I also tried

```
myFile1 = vertcat({'subject',num2str(5_59)'ms',num2str(6_69)'ms',num2str(7_79)'ms','number','condition'}, myFile1);
```

But it seems like numbers create issues. Can anyone guide me in the right direction please? Many thanks.

Comment: `5_59` is not a proper number. and have you tried `vertcat(['subject',...])`?

Comment: @Crowley, if I use that, an error message appears `Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.` Although, the number of columns is the same as the number of labels..

Comment: I see. I think you should use `fopen` with `a+` permission (append and read) and using `fprintf` instead of `vertcat`.

Comment: I tried: `AAA = fopen('myFile1', 'a+'); myFile1 = fprintf({'subject','5_59ms','6_69ms','7_79ms','number','condition'}, AAA);` and it returns this error: `Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.`.

Comment: Use it properly. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish. Please [edit] the desired output into your question.